# Binding ItemTemplate in MvxListView

Tags: c#, android, listview, mvvmcross, listviewitem

I'm developing simple Android application with Mvvmcross v.6.1.2 and have a trouble with MvxListView ItemTemplate binding.
Here is my ListView, which is correctly binded to MvxObservableCollection Weather in my ViewModel:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <MvxListView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:divider="#000000"
                android:dividerHeight="3px"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Weather; ItemClick ListItemClickCommand"
                local:MvxItemTemplate="ItemTemplateId weatherListItem"
                SelectedItem="{mvx:MvxBind CurrentWeather}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and here is my ListView ItemTemplate:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#ffffff">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        local:MvxBind="Text WeatherName"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What's wrong in `local:MvxItemTemplate="ItemTemplateId weatherListItem"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your layout:

```
<MvxListView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="3px"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Weather; ItemClick ListItemClickCommand"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="ItemTemplateId weatherListItem"
    SelectedItem="{mvx:MvxBind CurrentWeather}"/>
```

First issue here is

```
local:MvxItemTemplate="ItemTemplateId weatherListItem"
```

`MvxItemTemplate` when used in a `axml`/`xml` file, it refers to a layout to use as the item template. This will be a layout you have in your android resources. In order to point it at one of your resource layouts you need to write it like as follows:

```
local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/nameoflayout"
```

This will give the ListView a ID that matches your layout when it is inflated.

The other issue here is that you are mixing Xamarin.Forms XAML attributes with Android attributes:

```
SelectedItem="{mvx:MvxBind CurrentWeather}"
```

This line won't inflate, because there is no attribute called `SelectedItem` in `MvxListView`. If you wish to bind a public property, it needs to be done in `MvxBind`.

```
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Weather; ItemClick ListItemClickCommand; SelectedItem CurrentWeather"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your ItemTemplate layout called "weatherListItem"? If so, you need to specify the ItemTemplate and SelectedItem as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <MvxListView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="3px"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Weather; SelectedItem CurrentWeather; ItemClick ListItemClickCommand"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/weatherListItem"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Some sample code available here: 
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/WorkingWithCollections

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer. Yes, I try to use weatherListItem.axml in Resources/layout folder as template for ListView item.  May be a weatherListItemView.cs file is required?

Comment: The way you are defining your ItemTemplate looks wrong. You need to define it like this: `local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/weatherListItem"`